# OpenGL symbols highlighting error in visual studio code for Mac

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, visual-studio-code

When I wrote c++ code in vs code for Mac, the editor keeps showing red underline warnings for OpenGL symbols. For example:

```
#include <OpenGL/gl.h>
...
glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);
```

Meanwhile, I cannot use "Go to Definition" on these OpenGL files and functions. My code is correct and can be successfully compiled.

I tried to add "/System/Library/Frameworks" to "includePath" slot in the file ".vscode/c_cpp_properties.json", but it doesn't work.

Anyway to make this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following link to see the relevant issue:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/743